# Do Cuban Citizens travelling with a Cuban passport require a Visa to Transit CDG or AMS

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas

Travelling from South Africa to Mexico transiting through either Paris (CDG) or Netherlands (AMS), will a Cuban Citizen require a Transit Visa for either of the two Countries?
Person will be staying at the Airport and not entering the Country.

Comment: AFAIK the only TWOV option in Schengen for Cuban citizens is Frankfurt.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that you are on a single ticket (source: [TIMATIC](https://www.copaair.com/en/web/us/timatic)) :

> Nationals of Cuba with a normal passport transiting through Paris
> (CDG), arriving from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed
> onward ticket for a flight within 24 hours to a third country which is
> not a Schengen Member State. They must:
>
> - have a visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania or USA, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for their next destination.

> Nationals of Cuba, transiting through Amsterdam (AMS) and arriving
> from a non-Schengen Member State with a confirmed onward ticket for a
> flight on the same aircraft or for the first connecting flight to a
> third country which is not a Schengen Member State. They must:
>
> - have a visa issued by Bulgaria, Canada, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland (Rep.), Japan, Romania or USA, and
> - stay in the international transit area of the airport, and
> - have documents required for the next destination.

If you fill the requirements, you don't need one

Else, you need an Airport Transit Visa (ATV).

This also applies if you are on multiple tickets, but this time do **not** apply for an ATV, instead you need a full C-visa as you will leave the transit area.

Comment: Why isn't an ATV sufficient?

Comment: An ATV would be enough if the "stay in the international transit area of the airport" and "have documents required for the next destination" conditions are fulfilled.